# Changing crankset

Tags: crankset

I'm new to mtb and have just purchased and waiting delivery on a Giant Stance 2, I would like to convert to a 1x9 with a smaller crankset, would I have to adjust my chain to suit a smaller single crankset, and is it simple to do? Many thanks

Comment: When you change tooth count on the front or the rear you may need to adjust your chain length.  This if the chain needs to be shorter you can cut it shorter, but if longer then you need a new chain.  There are instructions online to tell you how to figure out correct chain length and how to "break" and rejoin the chain.  (Joining technique depends somewhat on the brand of chain.)

Comment: I provided a useful answer but I am always perplexed by people buying a bike and then wanting to swap out a major part.

Comment: Why don't you cancel your order for this bike and instead buy one that actually meets your needs?

Comment: Cheers guys for the reply, the funds will not stretch to a higher model, plus its cycle to work scheme with a giant supplier. I was thinking I would slowly upgrade the parts.

Comment: Ride it the way it is.  Once you get several thousand KM into it then make a decision about what might be an upgrade.

Comment: Maybe if you explained WHY you want to change your drivetrain.  What's wrong with a 2x9?

Answer (score 2):

According to the [Giant Stance 2 web page](https://www.giant-bicycles.com/us/stance-2) the bike comes with a 36/22 cranks and an 11-36 cassette.

You could swap the crank for a single chainring one. If the new chainring is between 36 and 22 teeth you will not have re-size the chain. If you want a chainring under 22 teeth then you will have re-size the chain and remove some links.

Breaking a re-joining a chain is not a very difficult thing to do, especially if the chain has a quick-link style connector. I linked a couple of Park Tool video's below.

Comment: Argenti Apparatus, thanks for the info and video. Much needed advice